# editing android studio dependencies

Tags: java, android

I am new on android studio so I created a new project when I try to debug and run the application on external emulator android studio will shown this error got this error :

'app process Debug Resource' failure then I added this lines to "build.gradle":

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() 
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() 
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

then I tried to run it again I got this error :
build was configured to prefer settings repositories but repository google was added by build file 'build.gradle':17
please help me.

...........................

Answer (score 0):

You just update the below code in your build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() 
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
         maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
     }
     dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
   }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
 }
task clean(type: Delete) {
       delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```